# How would history be different if Communism was white supremacist?

Tags: magic

Let's assume Communism does the same as it does historically, killing x million Chinese, millions of Africans, Siberian indigenous peoples. However, instead of using far left rhetoric, it justifies its actions using White Supremacist ideology. Would this radically alter the system of justifications for all ideologies?

Comment: In this case, it won't be called Communism.

Comment: This already happened. It's called: colonialism/imperialism

Comment: Isn't that basically what the Nazi's did? Socialist ideals with white supremacy? Been there, done that...

Comment: How is the tag "magic" relevant?

Comment: To the folks who voted to close this. Stop and ask yourselves if you are voting to close because you are offended, or because you really think this should be closed.  Oddly, it looks like the questioner has already left, so maybe it's irrelevant here. But for future reference.

Comment: In the hypothetical society, are Marx, Trotsky, *et alii* considered to be whites?

Comment: @puppetsock I figure most people are voting to close it as an emotional knee-jerk reaction because "muh communism." The question is not poorly formed, though it is poorly tagged. It's not really world building, but could easily be edited to make it fit world building. Sadly no one is giving feedback as to why they're voting down, probably because they don't have a good reason to.

Comment: @puppetsock I am actually seeing zero votes to close here, unless your comment provoked them to all be withdrawn (probable? not likely since you didn't ping anyone except the author) I'm going to assume that you mean down-votes, which under the circumstances seem not inappropriate.  Also Voting to close as too broad. In order to justify an ideology one has to define it, the question asks about changes to "all ideologies", with conspicuous lack of clear definitions and parameters. Waaay too broad.

Comment: Your question suggests the deaths of Chinese, Africans, & Siberians happened historically based on leftist ideology, and want the same death rate but based on white supremacist ideology. In either case the deaths are caused by power politics, nationalism & racism. Only the justifications have changed & nothing else.

Comment: There is a distinct contradiction about the Chinese deaths in your question. They were caused by catastrophic bad policies; the Great leap Forward & The Cultural Revolution. It's hard to see how white supremacy would cause Chinese to kill other Chinese when they were, mainly, all the same ethnic group. It would be like Nazis killing Nazis based on white supremacism. Although they were good at killing one another for other reasons.

Comment: Isn't that what they did

Comment: Your question is conflating economic systems (communism,socialism,capitalism) with cultural systems, for lack of a better word.  Soviets tried to wipe out the Cossacks, the Khmer Rouge targets ethnic minorities, as did North Vietnamese.  But, it was because those specific social groups effectively withstood the attempts of the collectivist government to change their historical social systems.

Comment: To the gentleman conflating Nazism as being Communism + White people best, this would be entirely incorrectly. Nazism is short for Nationalist Socialism, which, if anyone actually define the 2 terms, are basically antonyms. The entire point of socialist theory was for the world's workforce to be in charge of who benefits from work done (i.e. you deserve equitable wages on the basis of your work - your boss shouldn't underpay you because he/she wants to live the nice life). Nationalism refers to pride in one's own people/nation/state to the point of insanity.

Comment: The opposite part comes into play when you realize that socialism asks for the world's workers to rise up, whereas the Nazis wanted Germany and its Aryan race to reign supreme. Socialism doesn't care about race unless it's to make power moves to make sure people aren't affected by racism (effectiveness of this can be debated). Communism as @EDL pointed out is an economic system that stems from certain values in socialism. Now, how these systems have been designed/theorized and implemented can also be debated. For example, the Central American governments had themselves removed by the CIA.

Comment: Now the killings by Soviets and the Khmer Rouge can be directly attributed to the madness of their absolute leaders. In 1933 (I think) Stalin decided to purge the hell out of his own party by forcing people to rat each other out even when no one was guilty of anything, whereas Pol Pot was just an insane dude who wanted to get rid of anyone who might get in the way of his agrarian utopia (i.e the smart people of his country, anyone who looks different, etc.). The North Vietnamese were also paranoid of their ethnic minorities, but so was the South.

Comment: The killing of millions like this isn't a symptom of different economic systems. It's a symptom of the character of those holding power. Also, it doesn't matter if someone calls themselves Communist but act like Nazis - then they're closer to Nazis, yes? Maybe not in their opinion, but by standard definition. If it looks, smells, and sounds like a fish, but calls itself a dog, it still means that it's a fish, right? So, your solution should be to either make a Communist regime that acts like Nazis, or a Nazi regime that acts like Communists.

Comment: Do you think it would be different if Communists were openly white supremacists

Answer (score 3):

Communism wouldn't have had the same effect - one of the main motivators was for the workers to overthrow the ruling class with the idea of obtaining equality for all. At the time Russia was primed for such a motivator.

White supremacy wouldn't have moved them against their own (white) leaders but instead against other groups within Russia.

As such the world would be different to our own to such a degree that there is no point speculating.

Comment: Isnt that what Communism did

Comment: @user67320 The first paragraph is what communism did. White supremacy wouldn't have motivated the same actions.

Comment: Stalin? Genocided non-whites

Answer (score 3):

Communism, to say it simply, originates from Marx's economical value theory, that workers(proletariat) create the value and factory owners(bourgeoisie) unjustly appropriate it. Marx then proposed that it should be fixed by temporary dictature of proletariat which would build true communism where the economic value is equally distributed. No society succeeded to progress to the second step, AFAIK.

To somehow bake white supremacist ideology into middle of this makes no sense at all. So (at least to me) the question is absurd.

Comment: True, adding that feature makes no sense. But then, it makes no sense without that feature either...

Comment: Isn't that what Marx did